# Asus X200MA Laptop fails to start

Tags: boot, bsod, hardware-failure, asus-laptop

My Asus X200MA Notebook (Windows 8.1 64) that failed to start, started well at service center after over 12 hours of charging. It was returned to me stating nothing is wrong with it.

It however randomly shuts down or Windows 8.1 gives BSOD (BAD POOL HEADER or MEMORY MANAGEMENT etc) and later fails to start. It becomes dead, no display upon pressing power button.

The only way it starts again is after following a very tedious procedure

1. Remove Battery & HDD, reinsert only battery and charge it for 3 – 4 hours
2. Even if it was fully charged, the charging indicator then starts Orange and then turns Green after 3 – 4 hours
3. Now pressing Power Button takes me to UEFI Setup, later insert HDD and it starts normally only to abruptly give BSOD or abrupt shutdown again after a while may be in a few hours

Nothing unusual was noticed when I ran Windows Memory Diagnostics and checked the HDD S.M.A.R.T parameters and also Battery Health. I also updated Firmware to latest v506 as available for this model. I even refreshed Windows 8.1 clean reinstall.

Is there any technical explanation for this behavior and observed workaround to start it again? Is this a result of some hardware component failure somewhere, may be on the motherboard?  Thanks.

Comment: Replace the BIOS battery? Can you replicate 2. with the hard drive unplugged and try to get into the BIOS/EFI menu?

Comment: BIOS battery is not accessible even after opening the keyboard panel. Yes I tried Long Pres Power Button without HDD too, but no luck.